# Highcharts: How to disable piechart tooltip in combination chart example

Tags: highcharts

I have something similar to the highcharts combination chart example, with a pie chart embedded into another chart.

However, what seems like the obvious way to remove a tooltip (`tooltip:{enabled:false}`) fails to do the job.

My attempt is reflected in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

Thanks!

Comment: You need to disable tooltip for all chart types or only for pie?

Comment: Only the pie chart.  See my comment in response to Ricardo below.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple return `false` into the tooltip `formatter`.

http://jsfiddle.net/QgsNK/

Comment: This works if you want to do conditional logic in a shared tooltip configuration.  But what if you want to override tooltip behavior for a certain series?

Comment: "But what if you want to override tooltip behavior for a certain series?" how tooltip should work / behave for series? It is only why, by tooltip formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You can check type of chart,

```
var s;
                    if (this.series.options.type === 'pie') { // the pie chart
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        s = ''+
                            this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                    return s;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QgsNK/1/

Comment: See my comment to Ricardo.